# How can I change the default login URL in Laravel 7.30.0

Tags: php, laravel

I have implemented "artisan ui vue --auth" module in my Laravel project and it's all working fine. I want to know if I can change the default login URL to some other URL e.g. 'controlcenter/login'.

I tried to change the route() in redirectTo method in Authenticate() middleware and cleared all type of cache, but no luck.

I am using Laravel 7.30.0

My routes in web.php

```
Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: On LoginController there something like  `protected $loginPath = '/login';`

Comment: Have you declared your Auth route individually or in group as Larevel's default?

Comment: I have edited the question with my route details

Comment: In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` to path might also be hardcoded. And those custom routes might be useless, because `Auth::routes()` will overwrite them. It's more alike nine routes than only two.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all the three route declarations you have done, because Auth::route() will add all the necessary routes for you. Instead add the following:

```
Auth::routes(['login' => false]);

Route::prefix('controlcenter')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
});
```

The Auth::routes() function will add all the routes except for the login route. The next block of code wraps around any route and prefixes them with some text, here controlcenter.

Then the login route is defined inside the prefix block to get the prefix. You can add any other routes in this block as well and all of them will get the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions
(LaraClassified version 8.0.7 or greater. JobClass version 7.0.7 or greater)

You have to add the code below in your /.env file:

```
ADMIN_ROUTE=admin123
```

In old versions
(LaraClassified version 8.0.6 and old. JobClass version 7.0.6 and old)

You have to update the file config/larapen/admin.php at line 25. Replace admin by admin123 like this:

```
'route_prefix' => 'admin123',
```